# Does Google Analytics module tracks superuser 1 out of the box?

Tags: google-analytics

Does [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module tracks superuser 1 out of the box?

UPDATE: Found this in the `.install` file of the module. What does it basically say about user 1? Can anybody explain them to me? Does it track uid 1? Thanks.

```
variable_set('googleanalytics_roles', $roles);

// Upgrade disabled tracking of "user 1" to new logic.
if (!$track_user1 = variable_get('googleanalytics_track__user1', 1)) {
  variable_set('googleanalytics_custom', 1);

  // Load user 1 object, set appropriate value and save new user settings back.
  $account = user_load(1);
  $account = user_save($account, array('data' => array('googleanalytics' => array('custom' => 0))), 'account');
  $messages[] = t('Disabled user specific page tracking for site administrator.');
}

// Delete outdated tracking settings.
db_delete('variable')
 ->condition('name', db_like('googleanalytics_track_') . '%', 'LIKE')
 ->execute();

// ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Does Google Analytics module tracks superuser 1 out of the box?

Yes, it does. In fact, the default value for the Drupal variable googleanalytics_track__user1 is 1, which means the control statement is executed by default.

```
if (!$track_user1 = variable_get('googleanalytics_track__user1', 1)) {
  // ...
}
```

What the code does is to save in `$user->data` the module settings, and delete the old settings.